# "Symbols not found for Architecture x86_64" for a MEX file that uses the CPLEX API in C

Tags: c, matlab, mex, cplex

I'm currently writing a MEX file in MATLAB that uses the CPLEX API in C to solve linear programming problems. Unfortunately, I run into a "symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64" problem when I attempt to compile and I have no idea of how to solve it.

Some basic information:

- I can compile `yprime.c` and other MEX files that do not use the CPLEX API
- I am using MATLAB 2011b on Mac OSX 10.7.2
- I am using the GCC 4.2 package included in XCode 4.2.
- I already applied the [XCode 4.2 Patch for MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-FR6LXJ/)

I would greatly appreciate any advice people may have. I'm including a verbose error report below.

```
-> mexopts.sh sourced from directory (DIR = $PREF_DIR)
   FILE = /Users/berk/.matlab/R2011b/mexopts.sh
----------------------------------------------------------------
->    MATLAB                = /Applications/MATLAB_R2011b.app
->    CC                    = llvm-gcc-4.2
->    CC flags:
         CFLAGS             = -fno-common -no-cpp-precomp -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.5  -fexceptions -Wall
         CDEBUGFLAGS        = -g
         COPTIMFLAGS        = -O2 -DNDEBUG
         CLIBS              = -L/Applications/MATLAB_R2011b.app/bin/maci64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -lstdc++
         arguments          =  -DMX_COMPAT_32
->    CXX                   = llvm-g++-4.2
->    CXX flags:
         CXXFLAGS           = -fno-common -no-cpp-precomp -fexceptions -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.5
         CXXDEBUGFLAGS      = -g
         CXXOPTIMFLAGS      = -O2 -DNDEBUG
         CXXLIBS            = -L/Applications/MATLAB_R2011b.app/bin/maci64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -lstdc++
         arguments          =  -DMX_COMPAT_32
->    FC                    = gfortran
->    FC flags:
         FFLAGS             = -fexceptions -m64 -fbackslash
         FDEBUGFLAGS        = -g
         FOPTIMFLAGS        = -O
         FLIBS              = -L/Applications/MATLAB_R2011b.app/bin/maci64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -L -lgfortran -L -lgfortranbegin
         arguments          =  -DMX_COMPAT_32
->    LD                    = llvm-gcc-4.2
->    Link flags:
         LDFLAGS            = -Wl,-twolevel_namespace -undefined error -arch x86_64 -Wl,-syslibroot,/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -bundle -Wl,-exported_symbols_list,/Applications/MATLAB_R2011b.app/extern/lib/maci64/mexFunction.map
         LDDEBUGFLAGS       = -g
         LDOPTIMFLAGS       = -O
         LDEXTENSION        = .mexmaci64
         arguments          = 
->    LDCXX                 = 
->    Link flags:
         LDCXXFLAGS         = 
         LDCXXDEBUGFLAGS    = 
         LDCXXOPTIMFLAGS    = 
         LDCXXEXTENSION     = 
         arguments          = 
----------------------------------------------------------------

-> llvm-gcc-4.2 -c  -I/Users/berk/Applications/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Academic123/cplex/include/ilcplex/ -I/Applications/MATLAB_R2011b.app/extern/include -I/Applications/MATLAB_R2011b.app/simulink/include -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -fno-common -no-cpp-precomp -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.5  -fexceptions -Wall  -DMX_COMPAT_32 -O2 -DNDEBUG  "addcutsmx.c"

addcutsmx.c:488:4: warning: "/*" within comment
addcutsmx.c:37: warning: 'free_and_null' declared 'static' but never defined
addcutsmx.c:38: warning: 'usage' declared 'static' but never defined
-> llvm-gcc-4.2 -O -Wl,-twolevel_namespace -undefined error -arch x86_64 -Wl,-syslibroot,/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -bundle -Wl,-exported_symbols_list,/Applications/MATLAB_R2011b.app/extern/lib/maci64/mexFunction.map -o  "addcutsmx.mexmaci64"  addcutsmx.o  -L/Applications/MATLAB_R2011b.app/bin/maci64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -lstdc++

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CPXLopenCPLEX", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in addcutsmx.o
  "_CPXLcreateprob", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in addcutsmx.o
  "_CPXLchgobjsen", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in addcutsmx.o
  "_CPXLnewcols", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in addcutsmx.o
  "_CPXLaddrows", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in addcutsmx.o
  "_CPXLlpopt", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in addcutsmx.o
  "_CPXLsolution", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in addcutsmx.o
  "_CPXLgetbase", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in addcutsmx.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

      mex: link of ' "addcutsmx.mexmaci64"' failed.

Error using mex (line 206)
Unable to complete successfully.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be missing `-lcplex` or the relevant linking instruction for cplex on your system.

The User manual says the correct include and linking  parameters are in readme.html of your cplex  distribution, along with sample projects and makefiles.

From [Using Cplex with Matlab](http://www.omegacomputer.com/staff/tadonki/using_cplex_with_matlab.htm) it says you have specify the full library linking path and include path.  Depending on what you are doing you may need to also specify `-lilocplex` to mex.

E.g. `mex   -I/cplex_include_fullpath   -L/cplex_library_fullpath   -lcplex  file.c`

Comment: Do I have to include  -lcplex as a flag in the mex command? 

I am fairly sure that I linked the header files correctly since the compiler spits out errors when I do not use the correct variable types in the CPLEX API. This makes me think that I also have to link a library, though the readme.html file does not specify one for the C API.

Sorry if the questions are silly - I'm just very new at this.